# cs231n: how to make the program run faster?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am interested in this course and also new to python. I try the first NN program but it is quite slow (mostly in the following loop).

```
# loop over all test rows
for i in xrange(num_test):
  distances = np.sum(np.abs(self.Xtr - X[i,:]), axis = 1)
  min_index = np.argmin(distances)
  Ypred[i] = self.ytr[min_index]
```

Is there way to accelerate it?

Thanks.

Comment: Loops are slow in python. If you want efficiency - avoid them.

Comment: Since this is about working code, isn't it a better candidate for [codereview.se]?

Comment: @DavidRawson, thanks. I ask here because I see people post similar questions. If they run the same code, they may have similar issue.

Comment: @lejlot, could you elaborate a bit how to? Regarding this particular code, I don't see where you can avoid loop. I am not sure how python would do it different way. Thanks.

Comment: Loops are fundamental in many programming language... Otherwise, there's recursive functions, pointer referring (eg labels)...

Comment: Add tag of numpy as it could be related how to use it more skillfully to accelerate computing.

Comment: There is nothing really to elaborate. Python has extremely slow loops. You have to **vectorize** your code to make it decently fast. It is not a trivial operation and requires some tricks to make it work. The other way around is to use Cython, which can make your loops faster http://nealhughes.net/cython1/

Comment: @lejlot, I really appreciate your comments. Just to contribute my own  observation, I try Cython via the introduction in the suggested link. It doesn't accelerate any significantly.

Comment: But why it is a loop problem? It is only one loop and within it the major chunk of computation is vector operation where numpy should do a good job, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself: The parallel approach introduced in this link ([Parallelise python loop with numpy arrays and shared-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068760/parallelise-python-loop-with-numpy-arrays-and-shared-memory)) seems to work, basically cython, prange, gil, openmp and other tweaks.