# Parallel programming in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

My project was to do some parallel algos in C using OpenMP.
Now I would like to do the same project in Python.
Is there anything available similar to openmp for python?

Comment: You might find this list useful: http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: It won't be parallel in CPython, unless the code you're invoking has big chunks of C code in it.  Python is not a very good platform for doing anything parallel.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368486/openmp-and-python

Comment: My opinion is to look at IPython (http://ipython.org) and examples of how they use zeromq to do parallel processing (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_intro.html).  You could stick with iPython or try zeromq (or another messaging system) + multiple python interpreters yourself.

Comment: I'd suggest using Ray https://github.com/ray-project/ray, which is a library for parallel and distributed Python. It let's you run the same code on a single machine and a large cluster and also provides a clean way to parallelize both functions and classes (using "tasks" and "actors").