# Python native features for parallel processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

This is an assignment I am working on.

I have been asked to write a sample parallel processing program using native python features. I can write the code but the problem is - even after searching I cannot find a native parallel programming feature in python.

Since we have to import "multiprocessing" module - it is not native. I just cannot find which feature is available to use.

Already checked following threads but they use multiprocessing:

[Parallel programming in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072874/parallel-programming-in-python)

[Python multiprocessing for parallel processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753306/python-multiprocessing-for-parallel-processes)

[How to do parallel programming in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your definition of "native" is too narrow, or your understanding of the term "import" is mistaken.

The `multiprocessing` module is part of *Python's standard library*. Every Python implementation should have it. It is a native feature of Python.

The term "import" should be understood as "make this module available in this program", *not* as "add this non-native feature to the language". Importing a module does not change the language.

**Edit:**

In Python 3 you could make *concurrent* programs with `async def` and `yield`. But that shouldn't be considered real *parallel* processing. You might call it cooperative "multitasking", but it isn't really. It's task switching.

Comment: I agree to your opinion but my professor did not buy my argument. Will try again though! Anyways, do you know anything else that he might be referring to which does not need import? Thanks !