# How to check OpenMP usage in python graph-tool

Tags: python, graph, openmp, graph-tool

I am using python `graph-tool` for [this](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/flow.html#graph_tool.flow.boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow) algorithm in order to find min-cut in a large graph. My algorithm needs several calls to this function, and it seems to be the bottleneck. So I want to ensure if it is being run as efficiently as it could be i.e. using `OpenMP`.

However, on changing number of threads using `openmp_set_num_threads(n)`, I get the same time for different number of threads viz. 2, 24 and 128.

Is there a way to check if `OpenMP` is being used by the `graph-tool`? I have checked the number of threads using `openmp_get_num_threads` and it is correct. Also how to enable `OpenMP` in case it is not being used by the `graph-tool`?

Alternatively, is there a way to check if some particular function of `graph-tool`, `boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow` in our case, uses `OpenMP`?

Comment: How do you use openMP with Python? There is no direct support, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368486/openmp-and-python)

Comment: @Imontigny I am using the python library [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) which is implemented in C++, and thus can use `OpenMP`. At least this is what they claim they do.

Comment: Ok, can you print the output of graph_tool.openmp_enabled() and graph_tool.openmp_get_num_threads()?

Comment: `True` and `correct number of threads` respectively. The problem is that the function call to `boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow` takes the same time for different `num_threads`.

Comment: Ok, in the graph-tool source code they include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp> and I don't see any openMP pragma in the corresponding file [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp). It seems that this algorithm is not implemented in parallel. Only a part of graph-tool is parallelized using openMP, I found some omp pragma for pagerank for example. (You can do "grep -wr omp *" in the source folder of graph-tool)

Comment: Yes, that explains the same timings.. Thanks.

However does `graph-tool`  mentions in its documentation which functions are parallelized and which are not?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see such a description.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile there is a function for that:

```
> import graph_tool as gt
> gt.openmp_enabled()
True
```

> Return `True` if OpenMP was enabled during compilation.