# Thread scheduler in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to rewrite a few C OMP programs in Python for demonstration purposes. However, I cannot translate the loop scheduler one can find in C (example below)

```
pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("\n Process = %d, i = %d", omp_get_thread_num(),i);
```

Specifically, I need to demonstrate the differences between a dynamic and a static scheduler.

Is there such a thing as a thread scheduler in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dynamic thread scheduler in standard library - `concurrent.futures.thread.ThreadPoolExecutor`. I don't think that Python can do static compile-time scheduling. Python does very little at compile time, if you can even say compile-time about a language which is mostly interpreted.

Static scheduling would also make little sense, because of GIL (Global Interpreter Lock).

In theory this could be done by exposing bindings to some C library or using other flavours of Python than CPython, but imo Python is just not made for this kind of stuff :P. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742152/9392216) answer.