# Cloud Computing for Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-synapse

I run monte carlo simulation that takes 30 hours for 1000 sims using my desktop. Has anyone used azure, databricks, or any other cloud tools to significantly improve speed/runtime? I'm thinking parrallelization but am struggling to find a library or packages that can help with that. Does anyone have any ideas or experience in this area??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from the tags that your code is written in Python. This gives you several options:

- At a high level, you can use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module to run your Monte Carlo code *concurrently* (or even in parallel).
- If you know `C` or `Fortran`, you can port the expensive part of your code to C or Fortran and then use [Cython](https://cython.org/) to call it from your Python main function. This also allows you to use [OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368486/openmp-and-python) for shared memory parallelism.
- As a personal comment: 30 hours for only 1000 Monte Carlo samples seems quite excessive, even in Python. Perhaps there is a bug in your code that leads to this.

This list is probably not exhaustive.

In general cloud computing performance depends on what the vendor is offering and more importantly, on **what you are willing to pay for**.
AWS for example does offer APIs for parallel programming but you also have to know how to use them.