# How to share the large class member variable between the processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I have a class that contains a **large** member variable. I want some computation to be applied to this variable concurrently.

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.x = numpy.random.random((1e6,)) # some really large array
    def func(self, t): # a function that is expected to run concurrently
      # some computation that uses self.x
      return 0 # here I just return 0 for simplicity
```

I call the class this way (using pathos's `multiprocess`):

```py
from multiprocess import Pool
a = A()
pool = Pool(16)
results = pool.map(a.func, range(16))
```

It is very slow. I suspect it is because the large array is copied to every process, instead of being shared. How can I share this large class member variable between the processes?

P.S. I used pathos's `multiprocess` instead of Python's `multiprocessing` because the latter cannot pickle instance method.

Comment: Yes, the class is copied to each process, so the array is copied.  You may be able to use a shared memory array.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675766/2379433 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7894791/2379433